# How to solve an error in running Coffeescript on sublime text 2?

Tags: coffeescript, sublimetext2

When I try to run coffeescript file,it is not working for running.I can compile the file but can run it.

This is my build settings:

```
{
    "cmd": ["coffee.cmd","-c","$file"]
,   "selector": "source.coffee"
,   "working_dir": "$project_path"
,   "variants":
[
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "cmd": ["coffee", "$file"]
    }
] }
```

I already put the binary file location to environment variables. Every times I run the coffee scripts,it gives me the following error.

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd:  [u'coffee', u'D:\\coffeescript\\demo.coffee']]
[dir:  D:\coffeescript]
[path: C:\ColdFusion9\verity\k2\_nti40\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Samsung\AllShare Framework DMS\1.3.06\;C:\Program Files\Samsung\AllShare Framework DMS\1.3.06\64bit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Calibre2\;D:\4.Application\#Tools\Console2\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\bin\;D:\LINGO14\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Ruby200-x64\bin;C:\Users\aungt_000\AppData\Roaming\npm;]
[Finished]
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2):

The `cake.cmd` and `coffee.cmd` files should be found in the `%APPDATA%\npm\` directory if you did a global install as [recommended](http://coffeescript.org/). You can add that directory to your `PATH`, and I'd also recommend hard-coding the entire path (`"c:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\npm\coffee.cmd"` for example) into your `.sublime-build` file so it doesn't get lost.

Comment: This helped me out with this problem: http://kevinpelgrims.com/blog/2011/12/28/building-coffeescript-with-sublime-on-windows